# Replace {username} with the username of a client

Tags: php

How would I go about replacing {username} with the username of the client when doing a mass mail? I have the following code, but it only puts the first user for all of the emails.

```
if(isset($_POST["sub"]))
{
    $server = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["srv"]);
    $subj = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["subj"]);
    $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["msg"]);

    if($server == "all")
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `testing`");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `testing` WHERE `srv` = '$srv'");
    }

    while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $subj = str_replace("{username}", $results["uname"], $subj);
        $msg = str_replace("{username}", $results["uname"], $msg);

        mail($results["mail"], $subj, $msg, $headers);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try changeing `$msg` name in your while loop with `$tmp_msg` instead (also replace it in the `mail(...)` - @Black0ut 's reply clarifies why this is done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you replace the username placeholder ({username}) with the first username and the next time you try to replace the username placeholder with the 2nd username the username placeholder doesn't exists in the $subj string anymore.

Do this instead :

```
while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $userSubject = str_replace("{username}", $results["uname"], $subj);
    $userMessage= str_replace("{username}", $results["uname"], $msg); 
    mail($results["mail"], $userSubject, $userMessage, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it must be something useful.